# Is there any php framework which exactly reflect the msaccess

Tags: php, database, frameworks

I am fond of dbstructure definition of msaccess which lets defining at once and creating the data entry forms, datatables and reports at once easily.

I have been searching for some framework which would generate the data entry forms, data tables and reports easily. I guess the only thing I need to define is complete datatable structure.

Is there any like that or better one than that?

**EDIT:**

well i am afraid that PHP frameworks have been limited to programmers only. I would like to extend it with some automated functions like autoform in msaccess which would generate data entry form, auto report for data listing. So that my development time would be again some less. I found doctrine nearly matching my specification but not sure as i haven't fully explored doctrine

Comment: I don't think anything *exactly* reflects MS Access (thank God?). PHP frameworks are designed for programmers, you're expected to do at least *some* programming. MS Access is designed for business people who are not expected to know anything much about computers at all. Have you had a look at any frameworks yet and could you tell us what you didn't like about them?

Comment: Some frameworks have scaffolding functionality, ie they will create CRUD forms for you quickly to get you started. However you still need to write some code around them. Look at http://www.symfony-project.org/forms/1_2/en/04-Propel-Integration#chapter_04_the_crud_generator

Comment: thnx plz view my edits. I have worked with some frameworks like cake, doctrine and i myself have developed small framework on which my other projects are build. I would like to add the automated functions for simple tasks

Comment: well i think fanis got my idea. ok thnx for suggesting about scaffolding. i hope that's the exact word i have been searching

Answer (score 1):

Cake offers both "hard" (`bake`) and "soft" [scaffolding](http://book.cakephp.org/view/1103/Scaffolding), which should be very close to what you want. It's still only meant as a quick proof-of-concept tool and to get you up and running faster so you can concentrate on **programming** the business logic. It's not meant as a hands-off solution nor to be used in production.

What you seem to be looking for is a database frontend like [phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) or [SQL Buddy](http://www.sqlbuddy.com/), not a PHP *framework*.

Answer (score 1):

[Symfony](http://www.symfony-project.org/) provides an admin generator that builds all the forms on the fly and it will also update itself when you change your db schema. It is based on doctrine which you say you looked at so that would make things a bit easier for you.